# using two textboxes for filter two columns of gridview

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I want to filter my grid view according to inputs from two text boxes.
What I have:

```
 private void textBox1_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("[1] LIKE '%{0}%'", textBox1.Text);
 }

 private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("[2] LIKE '%{0}%'", textBox2.Text);
 }
```

for example the first column is "123" and second column is "clark".

Comment: So, what is the question?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the question could you please elaborate

Comment: i am getting directory of a folder and split it according to the condition...after split file name data comes into three columns.first is emp_no and second is data.i just want to condition two textbox for filter data by both emp and date

Answer (score 0):

Use this snippet to achieve what you need

```
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlConnection myCon = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd, myCon);
    adapter.Fill(ds);
    DataView view = new DataView();
    view.Table = ds.Tables[0];
    view.RowFilter = "ColumnName = " + TextBox1.Text.Trim();
    GridView1.DataSource = view;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

this is done using **ADO.Net**.

**Edit to match your question:**

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable resultTable = new DataTable();
        string path = @"\\192.168.96.80\hrmspics";
        recFolders(path, ref resultTable);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = resultTable;
        dataGridView1.DataBind();
```

From official Microsoft MSDN:

**Use the DataBind() method to bind data from a data source to the GridView control. This method resolves all data-binding expressions in the active template of the control.**

Comment: i have no database connection.actually i am displaying directory of a folder in grid columns

Comment: GridView1.DataBind();

Comment: Edited my answer for you

Comment: may i send you my complete code ? because data bind gives an error

Comment: Updated my answer as well

Answer (score 0):

In addition to setting the value of `RowFilter` you also need to bind the data to the gridview (again), so that it is updated on the UI.

So, you need to assign the data source, and call `DataBind()` on the grid - in both the methods. Like this,

```
GridViewMain.DataSource = dataView;
GridViewMain.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it my self but thanks all of you who trying to help me. :)

```
     private void textBox1_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("[1] LIKE '%" + textBox1.Text + "%' and [2] like '%" + textBox2.Text + "%'");
     }
```